# Unable to find pg_hba.conf file in postgres docker image?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using `postgres:15.1` docker image and unable to find the `pg_bha.conf` file inside the docker container. The find command returns nothing:

```
find . -name "pg_hba.conf"
```

Where do I find it in the docker image? Or, how do I configure it when running postgres via docker?

Comment: Can you connect to Postgres? Then you can run `show hba_file;` to see the location

Comment: Wow. Got it. That was way to simple. It should have been easy to find it on Google. Thanks. I can now see it.